# Unable to create rvmrc, RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work

Tags: ruby, rvm

```
alex@ubuntu:~/Documents/ruby_projects/my_project$ rvm --create --rvmrc 1.9.3@my_project
```

this one gives me

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Why am I unable to create rvmrc this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be you've corrupted your `rvm` installation somehow. It may be possible to fix it by wrecking around in the various shell script files it incorporates, but the easiest way to cure that problem is to re-install it.

If re-installing on top of your existing install doesn't work, try removing it completely before installing with:

```
rvm implode
```

It's usually best to create a new shell after it's been destroyed in order to start with a clean-slate. RVM has all kinds of hooks that can persist in any existing shells even after it's been imploded.

Comment: `rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p327 (found in /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327)
=> (default)
   global
`. So it's working good.

Comment: `rvm -v

rvm 1.17.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
`

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the message and follow the instructions.

A basic use of rvm is to:

```
rvm [use] <ruby-version>
```

where omitting the use keyword is still meaning to use a ruby but will not display a message.